# Sed script that removes numbers from file

Tags: regex, sed

I am given data in the following format:

```
comp.os.linux announce 0000002587 02190 m

comp.arch 00000 28874 y

utsa.cs.3423 00000000004 000000000001 y
```

I am supposed to process it so that it looks like:

```
comp.os.linux announce m

comp.arch y

utsa.cs.3423 y
```

I have tried  `s/^[0-9]//g` and it seems to work well but the last line is missing the 4 numbers

Comment: Made a correction in the 2nd line of your expected output, the last record should have been `y` and not `m`

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, printing the first and last field, including the second field if it's comprised of alphabetic characters only:

```
awk '$2~/^[[:alpha:]]+$/ {print $1, $2, $NF; next} {print $1, $NF}' file.txt
```

---

If you insist on using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)?.*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1 \2 \3/'
```

For the lines that do not have only alphabetic second field, this will have two spaces between the two fields, you could tack another `sed` for that:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)?.*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1 \2 \3/; s/  / /'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                              
comp.os.linux announce 0000002587 02190 m
comp.arch 00000 28874 y
utsa.cs.3423 00000000004 000000000001 y

% awk '$2~/^[[:alpha:]]+$/ {print $1, $2, $NF; next} {print $1, $NF}' file.txt
comp.os.linux announce m
comp.arch y
utsa.cs.3423 y

% sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)?.*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1 \2 \3/' file.txt
comp.os.linux announce m
comp.arch  y
utsa.cs.3423  y

% sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)?.*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1 \2 \3/; s/  / /' file.txt
comp.os.linux announce m
comp.arch y
utsa.cs.3423 y
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed 's/ [0-9 ]\+[0-9]\+//' file
```

Output:

```
comp.os.linux announce m
comp.arch y
utsa.cs.3423 y
```